# Deploying .xap file to non registered windows phone device?

Tags: deployment, windows-phone-8, xap

Hello everyone I have my app successfully deployed on windows device, we already have a windows  developer account. Now the client needs to test the app, how can we send him the app like ( apk files Android?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to unlock your clients device as developer device and then install it via the *Application Deployment* tool. You would have to send him only the XAP file which you can find in your bin folder.

If this is no option you could create a [beta test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj215598%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), here you would need the live ID of your customer. The app would run through the certification process so it isn't quite as easy as under Android.

Comment: Hello there thanks for your reply, however i had a question suppose i am generating the xap file with my windows dev account. And the client unlocks his device usuing his developer account. Will my XAP file work on his?

Comment: I have done this before too on WP8, though it has been a while.. Unlocking the phone allows to install apps from the desktop instead of the store, signing the app is another story and therefore can be done with another account.